# URL Amigables en Rutas dinámicas de React JS y Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Next JS y he creado varias rutas dinámicas con url similares a esto.

https://midominio.com/section/single-product/02694f7a6e2fe82 y me gustaría que esta ruta fuera mucho mas amigable y poder usar el titulo de la pagina en lugar de los datos dinámicos que estoy enviando sin perder la funcionalidad que tiene actualmente, agradezco si alguien me puede indicar como puedo hacer eso, el resultado que deseo es https://midominio.com/titulo-de-la-pagina

Answer (score 0):

Hablo de cabeza pero cuando quieres ir a un single product se debería de hacer algo así

```
<Link href={ `/section/single-product/${nameProduct}`} >
```

y luego en el archivo del producto algo así

```
const router = useRouter()
const product= PRODUCTS.find(item => item.name === router.query.name)
```

En router.query.name name creo que era el nombre que le habías dado a las paginas dinámicas [name], [id], etc